# What sort of join in mysql should I use to achieve this?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
Table A

id      name
---     -----
1       Foo
2       Bar
3       Fred
4       Joe


Table B
id      tablea_id   result  date
---     ----        ----    ---
1       1           A       02/04/2015
2       2           A       02/04/2015
3       1           B       03/04/2015
4       1           C       04/04/2015
```

How would I be able to achieve a result set that looks like this? What joins would I need in order to 'cycle' what is in table A?

```
date        tablea_id   result
---         ---         ----
02/04/2015  1           A
02/04/2015  2           A
02/04/2015  3           NULL
02/04/2015  4           NULL
03/04/2015  1           B
03/04/2015  2           NULL
03/04/2015  3           NULL
03/04/2015  4           NULL
04/04/2015  1           C
04/04/2015  2           NULL
04/04/2015  3           NULL
04/04/2015  4           NULL
```

Comment: I assume the third row in the desired results should be 02/04/2015.

Comment: yes, sorry ill edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want a `cross join` to generate all the rows and a `left join` to bring in existing values:

```
select d.date, a.tablea_id, b.result
from a cross join
     (select distinct date from b) d left join
     b
     on b.tablea_id = a.tablea_id and b.date = d.date
order by d.date, a.tablea_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You just saved me hours

Answer (score 0):

> What joins would I need

An `OUTER JOIN` and most probably (per your posted expected result) a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: How would I use them?

Comment: SELECT
*
FROM
 TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB on TableA.id = TableB.id   Does not produce the desired result

Comment: you are joining on wrong column. you should join on `tablea_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
select ab.id,ab.date,b.result
from
(select a.id,b.date
from(select distinct id
from table_a)a,
(select distinct date
from table_b)b)ab
left outer join 
table_b b
on ab.id=b.id
and ab.date=b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This Simple Query using Full Outer Join. [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/BZU43254)

```
            select distinct a.date,a.id as tablea_id ,result from B b
            full outer join
            (
            select a.id,b.date from B b,A a
            )A on  a.id=b.tablea_id and a.date=b.date
```

[image: Result]